# ArrayFormula not working as expected

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

My original array formula worked fine:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(E3:E="NULL"),"Unknown",E3:E))
```

With this formula whenever the sheet imported data that expanded the number of rows, the array formula would fill down.

But this new formula does not. The formula calculates for the cell in which it is typed, but does not automatically copy down:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(or(E3:E="NULL",ISBLANK(E3:E)),"Unknown",E3:E))
```

How can I edit my second formula to copy all the way down the length of the document?

Comment: I got it by just by using nested if() statements: =ArrayFormula(if(E3:E="NULL","Unknown",if(ISBLANK(E3:E),"Unknown",E3:E)))
BUt would be good to know if I can use nested OR() within an array like I initially tried to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In array formulas instead OR() use ADD() or the + operator

`=ArrayFormula(If((E3:E="NULL")+ISBLANK(E3:E),"Unknown",E3:E))`

Comment: Oh, interesting. Good to know. Thank you